# How to get Chrome to remember login on forms?

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, automation, remember-me

On many websites when you login via Chrome it will offer to remember your login details.

I have a login form and this does not happen.

Here's the form:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <label for="username">Email Address:</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" type="email" size="25" autocomplete="off"/>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" size="25" autocomplete="off"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

I'm assuming there must be some variable or header that needs setting to do this.

Does anyone know how its done?

Comment: Provide the HTML code of the form you are talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the autocomplete parameters from the form and now Chrome can store username and password here.