# ExtJS How to modify the textfield parameter autocomplete="off"

Tags: extjs4, extjs

Some modern (Safari, chrom, firefox) browser records informations and allows you to autocomplete some textfields when you come back.

I want to do it in ExtJS. I have a piece of answer here :

[How to get Chrome to remember login on forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401925/how-to-get-chrome-to-remember-login-on-forms/8405113#8405113)

But in ExtJS, I can not access to the parameter `autocomplete`. It is always hard coded `autocomplete="off"`. In the doc, I do not found how to modify it : http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text

Is someone has a simple answer to modify this parameter ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want to add an `afterrender` listener to the `textfield`, get a reference to the `input` element, and set its `autocomplete` attribute to "on". You probably also want to set its `name` (as that is how the browser remembers the value).

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4TSDu/19/

```
{
    xtype:'textfield',
    fieldLabel:'some field',
    name:'somefield',
    listeners:{
        afterrender:function(cmp){
            cmp.inputEl.set({
                autocomplete:'on'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that to make LastPass work you might need to remove `size` attribute from textfields. For some weird reasons Sencha is setting size=1 which is weird (was that because of IE6? maybe even IE5.5?).

Anyway this makes LastPass work. I guess you might want to remove `autocomplete` attribute as well for other password managers. Tested with ExtJS 6.5.

```
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'username',
        fieldLabel: 'Username',
        listeners:{
            afterrender:function(cmp){
                cmp.inputEl.dom.removeAttribute('size')
            }
        },
    },
```